# JavaFX WebView: Start Program, Input Data, Serve and Display Local HTML -> Refresh Data = Refresh WebView

Tags: java, html, javafx, webview

I need to be able to Open my application, input data via TextFields, send said data through FreeMarker and generate HTML, then display in WebView.

Here is where I'm falling off.

I have it all working however I cannot, for the life of me, figure out how to refresh the WebView to display the NEW current HTML doc after data input and rewrite.

It's overwriting the file fine, if I close and reopen, then re click my button, the WebView now shows the new data.

I'm sure the issue is that I'm using getClass().getResource(String):

```
URL link = getClass().getResource("EmailSigTest.html");
engine = webView.getEngine();
engine.load(link.toString());
```

How can I get this thing to change dynamically, i.e:

```
1. Input data
2. Write File
3. Refresh WebView to reflect new html doc
```

Where do I need to write and read the file to and from to make this happen?

I have tried engine.reload(); to reload the WebEngine... nothing.

I have tried adding an ActionEvent and .reload()... nothing.

Full Source Below:

```
public class SignatureGenFXMLDocController implements Initializable {
    private String firstName, lastName, directLine, title, cellPhone, lineOne, lineTwo;
    boolean social = false;
    @FXML private TextField txtFirstName, txtLastName, txtDirectLine, txtTitle, txtCellPhone;
    @FXML private CheckBox chkSocialIcons;
    @FXML Button btnGenerate;
    @FXML WebView webView;
    @FXML WebEngine engine;

    @FXML private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("You clicked me!");
        firstName = txtFirstName.getText();
        lastName = txtLastName.getText();
        directLine = txtDirectLine.getText();
        title = txtTitle.getText();
        cellPhone = txtCellPhone.getText();

        writeHtml();
        readHtml();
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    }
    private void writeHtml(){
        // Configurae Freemarker
    Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
    try {
        // Load the template
        Template template = cfg.getTemplate("src/signaturegen/template.ftl");
        Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();

            data.put("fName", firstName);
            data.put("lName", lastName);
            data.put("title", title);
            data.put("dLine", directLine);
            data.put("social", social);

            Writer console = new OutputStreamWriter(System.out);
            template.process(data, console);
            console.flush();
            // File output
            Writer file = new FileWriter (new File("build/classes/signaturegen/EmailSigTest.html"));
            template.process(data, file);
            file.flush();
            file.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TemplateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }     
    private void readHtml(){
        URL link = getClass().getResource("EmailSigTest.html");
        engine = webView.getEngine();
        engine.load(link.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18312297/webview-not-reloading-page-with-identical-url), reloading the same URL in the `WebView` does not work.

What you might want to try is delegating the reload to JavaScript in the page itself. For that you define a function in your page:

```
function reloadMe() {
  location.reload();
}
```

And call this function from Java:

```
private void readHtml(){
    URL link = getClass().getResource("EmailSigTest.html");
    engine = webView.getEngine();
    engine.executeScript("reloadMe();"); 
}
```

Further reading:

- https://blogs.oracle.com/javafx/entry/communicating_between_javascript_and_javafx
- http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/JavaFX/1500__JavaFX_WebEngine.htm
- [How to call a JavaScript function from a JavaFX WebView on Button click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19420753/how-to-call-a-javascript-function-from-a-javafx-webview-on-button-click)